# Objective-C++: Headers and Class Methods

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I've been learning Objective-C for the last few months with the goal of writing iOS games. I want to be able to make the games relatively easy to port to other platforms, so I've also been simultaneously learning C++. My plan is to write most of the game in C++ and write the drawing and game loop in Objective-C. I know (at least I've been told) this is possible, but there are a few things that I'm still confused about.

1. I'm still pretty new to C++, and coming originally from Java, is it a bad idea to have functions return type be void?
2. Is there a way to write class functions? ie. className.function(); rather than object.function();
3. I've never needed header files for my C++ files before. Could someone point me in the direction of an example? Preferably one that has a constructor method? I don't know what to make its return type. (It should be a pointer to the class right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your questions are about how to write C++, as that seems to be what you're asking.

1. Not at all, void functions are well-accepted in nearly all languages, C++ and Objective-C included. (Though many people prefer returning a bool success/fail value)
2. You're probably looking for `static` functions. These don't require instantiation, but there are some limits on their use (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyh8hetw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info).
3. **Any non-trivial C++ project should use header files.** They serve several purposes, including keeping your code more organized and modular, decreasing compile-time in many cases, and aiding in conceptualizing your design before you think about implementation.
   An important thing to note when breaking your class into .h and .cpp files is the use of the *scope modifier* `::` when defining functions. When defining the function `public void foo()` in your .cpp file, after having declared it in your header, you must use `public void ClassName::foo() { }`. This is because you defined `foo` while in the `class ClassName { }` block in your header, but you are now in the global scope.
   (As for your question about C++ constructors, if should be `public ClassName::ClassName();` and you don't need to return anything).

Now obviously, many of these points differ in Objective-C. For example, the `init` method (comparable to the C++ constructor) does, as you said, return a pointer to the object being inited. If you want specific information on writing cross-language apps, you should update your question to be more specific, or open a new question.

Comment: Thank you! I understand Objective-C and how to integrate the languages.

Answer (score 0):

1. No that is fine.
2. Yes:  Assume SomeClass.h:

   ```
   #pragma once

   class SomeClass {
   public:
       static bool myStaticMethod();
   };
   ```

   and in SomeClass.cpp:

   ```
   #include "SomeClass.h"

   bool SomeClass::myStaticMethod() {
       // A static method
       return true;
   }
   ```
3. See the first part of 2, above.

Some other notes:

A.  Change all your Objective-C interface code to Objective-C++ by renaming all the `.m` files to `.mm`.  This way you can use your C++ code freely.

B.  I couldn't think of a B.